# How to calculate a performance ratio when your goal is zero?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

When it comes to performance ratio the standard answer is quite simple. Let's say for example we have a car manufacturer who aims to manufacture $1000$ cars and he just made $900$ so have here $\frac{900}{1000}=90\%$ he has made $90\%$ of his objective.

But in another scenario we have flaws ratio our purpose is $0$ and we have made $10$ flaws so how can we calculate a ratio of the flaws since $\frac{10}{0}$ is not the right answer?

Comment: I find the downvotes mystifying.

Comment: The problem is, that your goal is having 0 flaws. In this case you can´t say, that you have made x-times flaws of the purposed 0 flaws. In general it is forbidden to divide a term by 0.

Comment: One difficulty is that the concept of performance ratio does not naturally apply to defects, as Hurkyl said. Another is that the goal you set is "be perfect", which is not really what quantitative analysis needs. It would be better to define some % of defects as "acceptable", and compare the actual % to it.

Comment: @Hurkyl I upvoted the question to counteract the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to compute the ratio of flaws to total.  So for instance if you had $10$ flaws among $50$ items, your ratio would be $20\%$, with the goal being $0$.

Comment: I want to evaluate the performance but in the same time taking into consideration my goal which is 0 flaws without including the total

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to make flaws and your target was 0, then 10/0 *is* the right answer.

However, your goal was probably not to make flaws: your goal is probably more like make unflawed widgets, and that is a very different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Flaws ratio is always connected to another measurement.
Like flaws/lines of code, flaws/hour flaws/car.

In that way you can measure your flaws made and set your goal:

Bake 100 breads with 0 flaws.